# Shopify Interact with product page HTML via app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

We plan to create a Shopify app but we face some problems to find in documentations how to interact with pages.

I`m not sure we must ask every time users to add codes and etc, so I need to know if I miss something.

I need to interact with the product pages in Shopify from an app.

I search and read all the web for this and everything is how to start but not the actual examples.

I know for the ScriptTags and how to include them but that is.
If someone can give me a simple example of how for example to hide the Buy button and insert something on instead.

I know how to select it with the default theme with JQuery but what about all other themes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to interact with the front page:

1) Inject some code in the page ( the live one )

2) Use ScriptTag as you mentioned.

---

The **code injection** script will modify the product template for example and inject your code if you like to do this automatically or you can instruct the user to do so on their own, but if they are not code savvy there might be issues.

In addition this code will live only on the live theme in most cases. And if the user likes to delete your app at a specific time you must be sure to write the logic in such way that it won't affect the site if your app is no longer present ( since it will be really hard to clean up the files once you add the code automatically )

For this approach you will need to use the Asset API.

You will need to get the content of the file with a [GET request](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/asset#show-2020-01) to the file and make a [put request](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/asset#update-2020-01) in order to update it.

---

The better approach is to use ScriptTag API.

This will allow the use of a script file that will be attached on EVERY theme. This will not modify the theme files in any form or shape.

It seems that this is the approach that you are looking for.

Please have in mind that you will be the one hosting the file from your app so pretty much you can write what ever you like there. So if you like to use jQuery you must be sure that the themes have included jQuery or you will have to add the jQuery core code inside your script.

As for how to write a script tag, there is a pretty straightforward documentation here: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/scripttag#create-2020-01

Comment: Thanks for the long answer but I already know this and I still dont understand - how for example to add a script somewhere which will hide the buy button for example.

Comment: @MartinTonev Well you just write the JS for the hiding part and create a ScriptTag with the API. I don't understand your confusion. The script will be present on EVERY page, so you can do  what ever you like as long as you target the button. The script is hosted by you and when you register it via the ScriptTag API Shopify automatically links to it in the theme, so you don't have to do anything additional.

Comment: Thank you for the response but as I explain in the question, I know what is ScriptTag and how it working. 

How to have something universal for all themes? I`ll target the button by for example $('#ID) but what if the user uses a different theme and there this ID is different?

Comment: @MartinTonev you can't. Each theme may have it's own implementation for the add to cart button, there is no universal class or name for it. Force the user to set a class or something else for the button or add an option in your app to allow the administrator to set a target class.

Comment: Thanks, that was my question I just was thinking so large product must have something like Hooks or anything and I was thinking I miss something.

But how is this possible, even WordPress has strict rules for this and developers can build everything around it?

Comment: @MartinTonev the liquid language is manly used for outputting content. It doesn't have control over the back-end in any way or form. So yes, it's very limiting compare to WordPress.